# Google Tag Manager not firing purchase event (Shopify)

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I've recently been going a GTM setup on Shopify and all has been going well apart from the purchase tracking. I'm finding that every other event tracks perfectly in GAUA, GA4 and Google Ads (Add to carts, initiate checkouts, etc) but whenever somebody completes a transaction there's no record of it.

I've done testing myself by firing purchases in different ways:

- With and without cookies
- Through GTM debugger
- On mobile data
- In incognito

and every single time my own purchases track and the Datalayer fires & fills perfectly. However it seems whenever there's a real customer order it doesn't track. I can see that the GTM container must be active, as in GAUA I can see that they have landed on the order confirmation page at the end of their journey, it just seems as though the datalayer never fills.

Here's my DataLayer code that is in Shopify's additional checkout scripts (not a plus store):

```
 <script>
{% if first_time_accessed %}
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];     
  window.dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  
  window.dataLayer.push({                      
    'event': 'EEPurchase',
    'pagePath': '/checkout/thank_you',
    'pageTitle': 'Purchase',
    'ecommerce':{
      'purchase':{
        'actionField':{
          'id': '{{order.name}}',
          'revenue': {{ order.total_price | money_without_currency | replace: ",", "" }},     
          'tax': {{order.tax_price | money | money_without_currency | replace: ",", "" }},       
          'shipping': {{order.shipping_price | money_without_currency | replace: ",", "" }},    
          'coupon': [
          {% for discount_application in order.cart_level_discount_applications %}
          {
            '{{ discount_application.title }}'
          },
          {% endfor %}
          ]
        },
        'products':[
        {% for line_item in line_items %}
        {
          'name': '{{line_item.title}}',
          'id': '{{line_item.product_id}}',
          'price':{{line_item.original_price | money_without_currency | replace: ",", ""  }},
          'brand': '{{line_item.vendor}}',
          'category': '{{line_item.product.type}}',
          {% unless line_item.variant.title == 'Default Title' %}'variant': '{{line_item.variant.title}}', {% endunless%}
          'quantity': {{line_item.quantity}}
        },
        {% endfor %}
        ]
      }
    }
  })
{% endif %}
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TRACKING-CODE');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you do a test purchase with a discount code? The `coupon` array seems to contain an illegal object which would result in an error (and thus the event not firing) if a user has a ordered with a discount.

Comment: @davidthorand No I didn't test with a coupon, when it would fire on my tests it would fire as coupon: [], should it fire as something like coupon:[{}] or just not fire at all? It's also worth noting that none of the real purchases used coupons either

Comment: @Emma what David is saying is that IF there are coupons the object will be invalid and you will have a JS error before, but if you tested with [] then, that's not the problem. (But still I'd suggest to remove the `{}` that are wrapping the discount title).




Can you confirm that you don't get any console error and the window.dataLayer variable is correctly updated?

Comment: @FabioFilippi Thank you for clarifying - I see what you mean now and I've fixed this for any future issues. I can confirm there's no console errors on the order confirmation page

Comment: @Emma Everything else seems correct. I'm quite sure it doesn't make a difference, but you can try move the TAG script before the `dataLayer.push`.  Other than that, I'm out of ideas sorry.

Answer (score 0):

just had this issue. I think this page is disconnected form your main site for security reasons?

either way, you need to add your GTAG and event script to the settings>checkout and account>additional scrips

add the head and body tags too.

(it wont let me post actual head and body tags)

--head--
GTAG script
--end head--

--body--
GTAG body script
--end body--

EVENT SCRIPT HERE

worked for me

Comment: Hi @james you got the script? if so can you please post here?

Comment: your event script looks fine to me, you just need to add your GTM tags (Both body and head) above the event script. then you should see it come through to GTM

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am using for coupon and what works for me:

```
 'coupon': '{% for discount_application in checkout.discount_applications %}
{{ discount_application.title }}
             {% endfor %}',
```

Also I am not using order object as it can't be accessed sometimes when the order status page is loaded. When user refreshing thank you page only. My items array looks like this:

```
{% for line_item in line_items %}
                      {
       'item_id': {{ line_item.product_id }},
       'item_name' : '{{ line_item.product.title }}',
       'item_variant': '{{ line_item.variant.title }}',
       'item_brand': '{{ line_item.product.vendor }}',
       'item_category': '{{ line_item.product.type }}',
       'item_discount': {{ line_item.line_level_total_discount | divided_by: 100 }},
       'price': {{ line_item.final_price | divided_by: 100 }},
       'quantity': {{ line_item.quantity }}
        },
      {% endfor %}
```